# Rearranging codeigniter mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I join the two functions below and make them inside the same `$qry`?

```
public function get_page_likes() {
    $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT p.id, p.tid, IF(SUM(pl.like) > 0, SUM(pl.like), 0) AS likes FROM pages_test AS p LEFT JOIN page_likes_test pl ON p.id = pl.pid AND p.tid = pl.tid GROUP BY p.tid, p.id HAVING likes >= 0 ORDER BY p.id, p.tid");
    return $qry->result_array();
}

public function get_page_dislikes() {
    $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT p.id, p.tid, IF(SUM(pl.dislike) > 0, SUM(pl.dislike), 0) AS dislikes FROM pages_test AS p LEFT JOIN page_likes_test pl ON p.id = pl.pid AND p.tid = pl.tid GROUP BY p.tid, p.id HAVING dislikes >= 0 ORDER BY p.id, p.tid");
    return $qry->result_array();
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJsEn.png

Comment: Please add your table structure and an example of the desired results.

Comment: @kisaragi  Thanks I just added my table structure, results and detailed description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query like that

```
$qry = $this->db->query("SELECT p.id, p.tid, SUM(pl.like) AS likes, SUM(pl.dislike) AS dislikes FROM pages_test AS p LEFT JOIN page_likes_test pl ON p.id = pl.pid AND p.tid = pl.tid GROUP BY p.tid, p.id");
```

return $qry->result_array();

Comment: Thanks a lot! This almost works :).  But it Is only fetching values from the "page_likes_test". It also needs to fetch data from the second table "pages_test" (as shown in the image). Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Mason! please check it i have changed query

Comment: I am glad to help you:)

Comment: Would you be interested in helping me solving similar problems in exchange for monetary reward?

Comment: add the question i will see on stack overflow?

Comment: Sorry I'm new I don't know much about stack overflow 

Comment: Oh right! Sorry I just understood. I'll find the next problem and post it soon. Kind regards

Comment: Give me the link of question here also in comment so i will get notification.

Comment: Good idea :) I'll make it very short clear and procise next to me. Thanks again for your help

Comment: if you are using CI you might as well take advantage of the query builder they have built in for you. This above method works but it is not the best method https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

```
public function get_page_likes_dislikes(){

  return $this->db->select('p.id, p.tid, IF(SUM(pl.like) > 0, SUM(pl.like), 0) AS likes, IF(SUM(pl.dislike) > 0, SUM(pl.dislike), 0) AS dislikes')
        ->join('page_likes_test pl', 'p.id = pl.pid AND p.tid = pl.tid', 'left')
        ->group_by('p.tid, p.id')
        ->order_by('p.id, p.tid')
        ->get('pages_test p')->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but for some reason I am getting an error saying 'unknown column p.id in field list' even though I have 'id' in my table